# How to train a deep neural network (tensorflow) on EC2 Spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using deep learning to do image recognition on a large data set with 100 caterogies. (compare to the size of cifar-100) I am now tuning the hyperparameters on a single machine without GPU. The training is extremely slow. I wonder if there is any existing method to do the training on EC2 Spark cluster?
I know there is SparkNet, but it seems to only support Caffe.

Comment: If you're going to use the EC2 cluster for "tuning the hyper parameters" then why not just broadcast the HPs across the cluster and have each learning app run with an individualized HP value?  A batch script with a for loop and some ssh-ing should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

As @Ramon commented , spark with tensorflow can be used for hyper parameter tuning by broadcasting the parameters. [See this example from databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/25/deep-learning-with-apache-spark-and-tensorflow.html)

```
def map_fun(i):
  import tensorflow as tf
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!', name="hello_constant")
    with tf.Session() as sess:
      return sess.run(hello)

rdd = sc.parallelize(range(10))
rdd.map(map_fun).collect()
```

Output:

```
['Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!',
 'Hello, TensorFlow!']
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been a couple of recent developments that make it possible to reuse your Spark cluster for training with TensorFlow:

- Yahoo! published [TensorFlowOnSpark](https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark), which uses Spark to manage a distributed TensorFlow cluster for you, and helps with issues like data ingestion, startup and shutdown.
- If you are running Spark on a Mesos cluster, you can follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/tree/master/marathon) to run TensorFlow on the same cluster.